# How to convert BCD to decimal and vice versa?

Tags: javascript, decimal, bcd

I am trying to write code in JavaScript to convert binary-coded decimal into decimal and vice-versa.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Removed my vote, misread the question.

Answer (score 5):

To encode and decode values using [Binary Coded Decimal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary-coded_decimal) (BCD):

```js
dec2bcd = dec => parseInt(dec.toString(10),16);
bcd2dec = bcd => parseInt(bcd.toString(16),10);

console.log(dec2bcd(42)); // 66 (0x42)
console.log(bcd2dec(66)); // 42
```

#### Explanation

Suppose you have the number 42.  To encode this as binary coded decimal, you place  '4' in the high [nibble](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nibble) and a '2' in the low nibble.  The most straightforward way of doing this is to reinterpret the string representation of the decimal number as hex.  So convert the value `42` to the string `'42'` and then parse this as hex to arrive at the number `66`, which, if you examine it in binary is `01000010b`, which indeed has a `4` (`0100b`) in the high nibble and a `2` (`0010b`) in the low nibble.

To decode, just format the number as a string using hexadecimal encoding, and then reinterpret this string as decimal.

Comment: thanks a lot @wyck, this is what I was looking for!